# How do you define indexes normally in PostgreSQL (coming from MySQL)

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

Like everything else, it seems PostgreSQL has much more powerful/complex indexing for tables. Perhaps someone can help me to know the default way to index columns.

*By default I mean integer/boolean columns which are used 90% of the time to filter table results.*

In MySQL I would simply create an index on a column with the same name as that column. I'm not sure what type was used (btree?) or what the implications of naming the index the same thing as the column were - but it worked.

Now moving to PostgreSQL I'm wondering if there is any problem naming the index with the same name (or any reason not too). Also, I'm wondering which type of index should be used for int/bool values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part the default index type (btree) will be fine.

The default index name (if you don't specify one in the CREATE INDEX statement) is based on the table and column name, typically something like *table*_*column*_idx. IIRC index names must be unique within a schema, so if you name your indexes with the same name as the columns you may run into trouble if the same column name is used in more than one table in the schema.

Comment: Ok, one other question - when you run your queries do you have to use the index names or can you use the column names and PostgreSQL will know to use the matching indexes automatically?

Comment: @Xeoncross: PostgreSQL knows which indexes are available and which ones to use.

Comment: Awesome. Oh and I forgot - are serial/bigserial indexed automatically like MySQL primary keys?

Comment: @Xeoncross no, but typically you define a column as `some_id serial primary key` and marking a column as primary key causes an index to be created on it. You can have a non-indexed serial column, or make it part of some other index, but in my experience you generally make serial columns primary keys.

Comment: Thanks @araqnid, I didn't know I needed to add `primary key` to the serial column definition. That would explain why my tables were showing 0 indexes.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to index booleans use a conditional index.  Most boolean values are either evenly distruted, in which case an index on just boole gains you almost nothing, since you'll be reading half one way or the other.  But, in instances where you have a boole where 99.999% of the rows are one value and the other 0.001% are the other value, creating an index on JUST that 0.001% makes sense:

```
create index mostly_true on tablename (somefieldIwantwhenboolfieldisfalse)
  where boolfield is false;
```

Note that this also works for multicolumn indexes.

```
create index mostly_true on tablename (col1,col2) where boolfield is false;
```

Comment: Interesting, so you are saying that indexing a table with 50/50 booleans isn't a good idea? Doesn't keeping that list of booleans in an index save PostgreSQL from having to read each row looking for the boolean value?

Comment: No.  Postgres has to read the rows anyway, because of its design.  Indexes only tell you where to look it up, not if the value is visible to your transaction.

Comment: Note that later versions of postgresql now support covering indexes, so this advice may or may not be out of date.